# What does a dialog box message "pictd quit unexpectedly" mean

Tags: macos

I received a dialog box message "pictd quit unexpectedly" in my Mac powerbook pro.  What does this mean?  My operating system is OS X (Version 10.11.2).

Comment: Did you try to google the error message? Please describe what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation:

> [`pictd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pictd.8.html) is a helper tool for the Cocoa frameworks.
> There are no configuration options to `pictd`. Users should not run `pictd` manually.

This isn't very helpful to the layperson, but `pictd` is essentially a programming helper tool to let developers read/render image files through OSX. Why it's quitting on you unexpectedly could be many reasons but mostly likely it's an error rendering a file; if there's a specific error being generated by a specific program, you might have luck finding it in the [system logs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26480/where-can-i-find-my-crash-logs).

Hope that can help.